# Masking Non-Stored Password Parameter on "Injected environment variables" page in Jenkins

Tags: passwords, jenkins, parameterized

I feel as though I must be missing something simple here - 
what I want to do is create a parameterized build, where one of the parameters is a password.  I do not want to store the password permanently in Jenkins.  So far I have been able to mask the password in the console output using the "Mask Passwords" plugin, but no matter what, the EnvInject's "Injected environment variables" page on any of the builds displays the password in plain text.

I've tried a variety of things, including, but not limited to:
Naming a "Mask Passwords" password the same as one of my password parameters
Naming an "EnvInject" passwords the same as one of my password parameters

I've found
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12423
but I think it just refers to masking passwords from the console output.

I've tried this on a couple different OS and version combinations, but right now I'm just attempting to get this to work on:
Windows 7 64bit
Jenkins ver. 1.470
Environment Injector Plugin 1.55
Mask Passwords Plugin 2.7.2

But I can't seem to figure this out.  I feel as though this is probably not an extremely uncommon setup, so I'm probably just missing something stupid.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Inject Environment Variable plugin via Flexible Publish plugin to inject an empty value into password parameter in the end of the build.
In the Injected Vars tab you will see an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the Mask Password plugin for Jenkins works (without the EnvInject plugin) pretty well. It can substitute the global password w/i a switch in an Invoke gradle script task e.g.:

```
-Psometask_password=${global_sometask_password}
```

It did not work when I tried to use the variable in a Windows batch command version of the same gradle task. Perhaps the plugin detects the “Switches” field in the Invoke gradle script task.

Comment: please add 4-space indentation to your code so that it is formatted as code